# Find all text matches in a current session of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search all open files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940675/how-to-search-all-open-files-in-eclipse)

I'd like to search for all matches of the text "the entry exists" within the current Eclipse session. How can this be done for all open files (instead of just searching through the currently opened source file, using CTRL+F?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search - File...

But it won't search in open files. It will search in the whole workspace, or in the current project, or in the selection, or in a working set, depending on the option you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can't search only in the open files. You can search in the whole project, whole workspace.  Go to the menu -> Search -> File Search tab -> Containing Text field .. and write there your text.