# how to do "Find All" for a keyword in opened document in Eclipse?

Tags: java, php, eclipse

Hi I want to do search for a keyword like $this->data in an opened php file in eclipse for all its occurrences just like what we do Find All in Dreamweaver or ctrl+f in netbeans,I have tried Ctrl+H and Ctrl+F but it didn't worked for me,anyone can tell me how to do it???Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search all open files in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940675/how-to-search-all-open-files-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

In the Search menu, click on File, enter the string you want to seach, make sure to have * in File name patterns (if you want to search in your whole project), then  click the search button.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse use combination of  : ALT + SHIFT + R

Comment: Hey,it is used to RENAME the resource(file) I am asking for doing Find All in an opened file for a selected keyword.